# I jumped off/ from the swing

Tags: phrase-usage

Most people would say that they jumped off the swing
 but why not jumped from the swing?

Comment: It is used, just not that extensively. That's all. Look at this [Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=jumped+off+the+swing%2C+jumped+from+the+swing&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cjumped%20off%20the%20swing%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cjumped%20from%20the%20swing%3B%2Cc0)

Answer (score 3):

If someone jumped *off* the swing, that means that he was previously on the swing.  Jumping *from* the swing could mean that he was next to the swing.  I could stand next to someone and say "roar".  If I succeeded in startling him, he might jump *from* me.  If he is standing next to the swing as someone riding the swing starts coming down, he might jump from the swing to avoid getting hit.  Jumping from the swing isn't used as much because it is ambiguous.